# How to add numbers within a list

Tags: python-3.x

```
the_list = ['diced tomatoes', 3, 'olives', 2, 'tomato soup', 3, 'tuna', 7]
def count_cans():
 print(len(the_list))
```

So in this list there are 15 cans of food. how do I make a function that counts and returns the total amount of cans in the list.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: `sum(the_list[1::2])`

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary then sum the values in your dictionary:

`the_list = {'diced tomatoes': 3, 'olives': 2, 'tomato soup': 3, 'tuna': 7}
sum(the_list.values())`

Answer (score 0):

Pick out the numbers and then add them up.

```
the_list = ['diced tomatoes', 3, 'olives', 2, 'tomato soup', 3, 'tuna', 7]
def count_cans (list) :
    sum = 0
    for element in list :
        if type (element) == int :
            sum += element
    return sum

print (count_cans (the_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
total_cans = 0
for food in the_list:
    if (isinstance(food,int)): total_cans += food

print(total_cans)
```

With O(n) performance, goes through the list once.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverFlow! As a general tip, it would be a lot more helpful for us to answer your question if you added what you've done so far like @Victor Wilson said, but nonetheless, we will try to help.

Think about what you may need to "increment" a "counter" variable (major hint here!). Since you are working with a list, you know that it is an iterable so you know you can use iterative processes like `for-loops/while-loops` and `range()` function to help you.

Once you find the "number of cans" (hint: type `int`), then you can increment that with your counter variable (hint: addition here).

Knowing what data types you're working with and what built-in methods that can be used with those types can be extremely helpful when learning to debug your own code.

And... by the time I finished my post, @bashBedlam seems to have answered you with a full program already ;). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add only the numbers in a list, you can extract numbers from that list and then `sum` that sublist. That would mean something like,

```
def get_number(whatever):
    try:
        return float(whatever)
    except ValueError:
        return 0


your_list = ['diced tomatoes', 3, 'olives', 2, 'tomato soup', 3, 'tuna', 7]
total = sum([get_number(i) for i in your_list])
```

However, if you tell us your actual problem statement, I feel we can tackle the problem more efficiently. You should more likely use a different data structure. Use a hash-map/dictionary if you know that the items (condiments) in your list are unique or maybe use tuple/namedtuple to provide a structure to your input data - name-of-item: count-of-item. And then you can use more efficient techniques to extract your desired data.

I feel like this is some homework problem, and I am not quite sure about the policy of SO regarding that. Regardless of that, I would suggest focusing on the ideas provided by the answers here and apply yourself instead of copy-pasting the (pseudo-)solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use range function with loop to count numbers. Range function return sequence of numbers and takes 3 parameters
Syntax
range(start, stop, step).
start and step are optional.

To learn about range function, visit
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

```
the_list = ['diced tomatoes', 3, 'olives', 2, 'tomato soup', 3, 'tuna', 7]
def count_cans():
    count=0
    for i in range(1,len(the_list)+1,2):
        count+=int(the_list[i])
return count
```

Comment: probably you meant `count += the_list[i]`
Anyway, there are simpler ways to do that. You can iterate over list skipping one and sum by `sum(the_list[1::2])`

Answer (score 0):

```
the_list = ['diced tomatoes', 3, 'olives', 2, 'tomato soup', 3, 'tuna', 7]
sum([the_list[i] for i in range(1,len(the_list),2)])
```

It works by :

- creating a new list using a comprehension of `the_list` index by a range
- starting with 1 and iterating every other value
- then passing that to the `sum()` function